# Создать массива deferred объектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо дождаться окончания всех deferred объектов

```
var defTimerOneQuestion = [];

$.when.apply($, defTimerOneQuestion).then(function () {

    finish();
});
```

Добавление в массив deferred объектов;

```
var defCurrentTimerOneQuestion = new $.Deferred;

defTimerOneQuestion.push(defCurrentTimerOneQuestion);

setTimeout(function () {

    defCurrentTimerOneQuestion.resolve();
    return defCurrentTimerOneQuestion.promise();
}, 20000);
```

Но deferred не стреляется, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в том, что складывать надо промисы

Comment: Заменил на    defTimerOneQuestion.push(defCurrentTimerOneQuestion.promise());   Но все равно не работает

Comment: Проблема в том, что `$.when` надо вызывать когда все обещания уже сложены в массив, а не заранее.